# How to keep MVC application running even after stopping debug in Visual Studio 15 IDE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In my local office system I have VS13 and in that I am keep my MVC application running even when I click **Stop Debugging (Shift + F5)**, I am trying to achieve the same in VS15 Enterprise edition in my remote client machine.

I don't know what setting I did in VS13 for this behavior, I tried out few solutions like setting Edit and Continue option in VS15 Debugging options and also tried to find out the same in website property but couldn't find it in VS15.

VS15 doesn't support this? Or am I not doing it right?

Kindly help me out.

Thanks,

Comment: Look at setting up your IIS to run a site from your `bin` folder of your project. I can't remember exact steps, but you will need to add it as a site in the `applicationhost.config` file of your IIS settings. You can then run IIS using the arguments to run your site by its ID. Hope this helps :) P.S here's a handy reference that might help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2011/04/22/test-your-asp-net-mvc-or-webforms-application-on-iis-7-in-30-seconds/

Answer (score 2):

You need to register the application in **IIS**. If you don't have IIS installed (i.e. using only IIS Express with VS), you need to install it.

1. Go to **Programs & Features**
2. **Turn Windows Features on or off**
3. Check items, to match this image:[image: Enable IIS]

You might need to restart your machine. After that's done, register Asp.NET by running following commands in the CMD:

```
cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319   
aspnet_regiis -i
```

After that is done, open the **IIS** (Start>IIS). 
There should be a default website with an application pool already created. Navigate to **Application Pools**, select your pool and edit its **Basic Settings**. Set your desired **.NET version** and set the **Managed pipeline mode** to **Integrated pipeline mode**.

Now locate your site in the tree-view. Right-click it and select **Add application...**
Set the path to your MVC App's folder, enter an alias (what comes after the domain name, e.g. localhost/MyMvcApp)

Build your app, close the VS and it should work.

Comment: I will try your solution and let you know, thanks for the inputs